# How to return ManytoManyField to string?

Tags: python, django

I want to return the ManyToManyField as a string but it turned out to be none. This is the result "Cart id: 36,whitet-shirt,products.Variation.None" I got

carts.models.py

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart                = models.ForeignKey(Cart,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    product             = models.ForeignKey(Product_info,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    variations          = models.ManyToManyField(Variation,null=True,blank=True)
    quantity            = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    linetotal           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,default=10.99,decimal_places=2)
    timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False,null=True,blank=True)
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{},{},{}".format(self.cart,self.product,self.variations)
```

products/models.py

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    product             = models.ForeignKey(Product_info,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    cat                 = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, default='size')
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price               = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    description         = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = VariationManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: what have you tried and which problem did you encounter?

Comment: It returned "None" when I wanted to return its title

Comment: This is a bit of an aside, but you have `product` as a FK on both `CartItem` and `Variation`. Can these products be different values, or should they always be the same? I suspect they should be the same, in which case I think you need to look at normalising your models a little ...

Comment: Thanks!! I'm very new to django and coding.i will take your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.all()`. Furthermore you probably want to join the textual representation of these `Variation`s, so you can `','.join(..)` these together:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):

    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        variations = ','.join(str(v) for v in self.variations.all())
        return "{},{},{}".format(self.cart, self.product, variations)
```

That being said, this thus means that `__str__` will often make an additional query to the database, I'm not sure if that is a good idea.